# Exception in "Main Thread" error while setting up beanshell

Tags: java, command-prompt, beanshell

got tasked to learn beanshell. so here i am trying to set up my first example using this [tutorial](http://www.philippeadjiman.com/blog/2009/10/17/beanshell-tutorial-quick-start-on-invoking-your-own-or-external-java-code-from-the-shell/)

I downloaded the jar file from [here](http://www.beanshell.org/download.html) like suggested, and placed it in my `C:\lib` folder, because it is the closest to the `C:\libs` that the tutorial suggested.

I ran the following in the command prompt and i get an `Exception in thread "Main Thread" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: bsh/Interpreter`

My current environment is geared for Struts1.X/Spring/Hibernate in Win XP. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to run it as follows, assuming I am in a command prompt in `c:\lib`

```
java -cp . -jar bsh-2.0b2.jar
```

Comment: i was using `.0b4.jar` from the download section. perhaps i should get back to using `.0b2.jar` instead for the GUI console. in the meantime i have been using `java -Xrs -Xverify:none -cp bsh-2.0b4.har bsh.Interpreter`

Comment: The name of the jar file is all that is different. Just sub your own. Seem my comment on you other question also.